# Correct syntax for seeding role/users after changing primary key for users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using the default ASP.NET MVC 5 project I can seed and roles using the following code. I'm struggling to get the syntax correct to update this after I've customized the primary key for users.

I get 2 errors in the Configuration class

`The type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be used as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method 'UserStore<TUser>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityUser'.`

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore<ApplicationUser>' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore<ApplicationUser, int>'`

How can I correct this code to account for change to the CustomUserStore and  CustomRoleStore?

The primary key changes are based on this [Change Primary Key for Users in ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity)

```
namespace IR.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {

            if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator"))
            {
                var store = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context);
                var manager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(store);
                var role = new IdentityRole { Name = "Administrator" };
                manager.Create(role);
            }


            SeedNewUser(context, "email@email.com", "****", "Administrator");

        }

        private async void SeedNewUser(ApplicationDbContext context, string email, string dummyPassword, string role)
        {
            if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == email))
            {
                var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
                var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email, LockoutEnabled = false, EmailConfirmed = true, SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };

                manager.Create(user, dummyPassword);
                manager.AddToRole(user.Id, role);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to make it work with the following customization

```
namespace IR.Models
{

    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
        }
    }


    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typical, manage to fix it soon after posting.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{

    if (!context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Administrator"))
    {
        var store = new CustomRoleStore(context);
        var manager = new RoleManager<CustomRole, int>(store);
        var role = new CustomRole { Name = "Administrator" };
        manager.Create(role);
    }

    SeedNewUser(context, "email@email.com", "****", "Administrator");

}

private async void SeedNewUser(ApplicationDbContext context, string email, string dummyPassword, string role)
{
    if (!context.Users.Any(u => u.UserName == email))
    {
        var store = new CustomUserStore(context);
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(store);
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = email, Email = email, LockoutEnabled = false, EmailConfirmed = true, SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() };

        manager.Create(user, dummyPassword);
        manager.AddToRole(user.Id, role);
    }
}
```